# Combine Authentication Scenarios with Azure AD

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure-active-directory

Azure AD is used as the authentication provider for a web application we've built.

We followed the Web Browser to Web Application Scenario listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-browser-to-web-application).
It's an application with several main sections. We'd like to add on new parts and use client-rendering technologies, like React or Angular.

For those technologies, we'd like to use a Single Page Application scenario as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa).
Since we're using React, we couldn't use the SPA scenario above exactly, as it was outlined. With [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi), we added the code to have authentication for the API calls in our addition.
The authentication happens with JavaScript side, but actually causes a page reload.

Is there some way to unify the authentication approaches of the Web Browser to Web Application and JavaScript to Web API scenarios?

EDIT:
I made a [sample project](https://github.com/irwinwilliams/ATaleOfTwoAzureAD_Scenarios) that tries to combine both scenarios for authentication.
In it, I suppose the question boils down to sharing logged-in information with the AuthenticationContext JS class.
On the TodoAPP controller I include this code to login:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
    if (!user) {
        authContext.login();
    }
</script>
```

The login step causes the browser to refresh, even though the user is already logged in, that's what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Can you expand on what you're trying to do? Specifically, what you mean by the unification of the two app topologies.

Comment: So, we've used Azure AD just for user authentication in the past. We'd now like to use it for securing our APIs as well.

Comment: AAD absolutely supports securing your Web API. For a quick primer, take a look at the `Adding access scopes to your resource application` section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications). I think the problem with your question is you are not asking a specific question which the community can give you specific guidance or solution on.

Comment: Will do a brief demo to highlight what my issue is.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I made a demo project and commented above about it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following web posts that outline how to use configure an ASP.NET project to protect both a Web App and Web APIs:

- [Use OWIN & Azure AD to Secure Both MVC UX and Web API in The Same Project](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/28/use-owin-azure-ad-to-secure-both-mvc-ux-and-web-api-in-the-same-project)
- [Authentication Protocols, Web UX and Web API](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/04/22/authentication-protocols-web-ux-and-web-api)
- [Controlling a Web App’s session duration](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/)

This will handle the scenario on the server side.

Comment: Great! Will check these out!